# How to get only declared members (not inherited) with Kotlin Reflection?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Is there any way to get only the declared **members** of a class (not inherited) with Kotlin Reflection?

Something equivalent to [`getDeclaredMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()), or `...Fields()`,  in Java, but for **members** and **JVM free**, which:

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class ... **but excluding inherited methods**.

Or like a binding flag, such as  `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` of dotnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the reflection is based on the class, So the following is only for the kotlin/JVM, not suitable for the Kotlin/JS or Kotlin/Native.

For the Kotlin/JS it supports limit, for detail, you can see this
[document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-reflection.html)

> The only supported parts of the API are: (::class),KType and typeOf

Firstly, you can use the `SomeClass::class.java.declaredMethods` to get the
getDeclaredMethods. That is the java method. Because the Kotlin file after compiled it is still a class. so you can directly use it.

You can also add the kotlin reflect to get the KClass, then use the `declaredFunctions` to get. Here is the [Document](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/)

> Returns all functions declared in this class. If this is a Java class, it includes all non-static methods (both extensions and non-extensions) declared in the class and the superclasses, as well as static methods declared in the class

For how to get the KClass, you can use the following code

```
 Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass").kotlin.declaredFunctions
```

Besides the method, the other property you can also get. such as

- declaredMembers

> Returns all functions and properties declared in this class. Does
> not include members declared in supertypes.

- allSuperclasses
- functions

> Returns all functions declared in this class, including all non-static methods declared in the class and the superclasses, as well as static methods declared in the class.

you can read the document using it.

Comment: Moreover, I mean members, and not only methods. I gave the example of Java `getDeclaredMethods` because there is not any `getDeclaredMembers`.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa, OK, I got it. In that way, it can get all the kclass , such as  declaredMemberProperties and so on.

Comment: @gidds, it only works in kotlin/JVM, because it base on the class

Comment: @gidds， you are right. I should add it